# masm x86 assembly does a dereference *only* return the value being stored at a given address

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have a basic buffer allocated for my program:

```
.DATA?
buffer DWORD 01FFFh DUP(?)
.CODE
MOV ESI, OFFSET buffer
```

I want to get the address of two values in the buffer, and push them onto the stack for a future reference:

```
LEA EAX, [ESI + 04h * 00h]
LEA EBX, [ESI + 04h * 0Ah]
PUSH EAX
PUSH EBX
```

And I later want to call a procedure that takes in a start address and an end address as parameters, with ESP and ESP + 04h as the parameters.

```
PUSH [ESP] ;ESP contains the end address
PUSH [ESP + 08h] ;ESP + 08h contains the start address
CALL myProc
```

However I am not sure if it would end up pushing the value found at the address found at the address ESP and the value found at the address found at the address ESP + 04h, or if it would just push the address found at ESP, and the address found at ESP + 04h because of the dereference.

For my situation I need to be able to 're-push' the address found at ESP, and the address found at ESP + 04h onto the stack.

To summarize, does a dereference *only* return the value being stored at the given address, even if the 'value' is another address?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, after first `push [esp]` the esp is adjusted to accommodate the newly pushed value, so the `[esp+4]` in next instruction is actually pointing to the original `[esp]` of first `push`. This is the reason, why often the `ebp` is initialized in the procedure prologue to be "stackframe" pointer :`mov ebp,esp` and then the `[ebp+4]` in further code will always target the same stack memory, even if you do additional `push/pop` (as long, as you don't modify `ebp`). If you insist on `esp` usage, you have to dynamically adjust the offsets after each `esp` change, i.e.: `push [esp]` `push [esp+8]`

Comment: Yeah, I realized that looking back at my code a while ago, since pushing  something new would also change what ESP points to! Looks like I should probably change the same thing in my above code example too. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LEA loads the "effective address". So you are pushing two addresses.

To get data from these addresses and push them, you could do something like:

```
        MOV     EAX,[ESP]
        MOV     EDX,[ESP + 4]
        MOV     EAX,[EAX]
        MOV     EDX,[EDX]
        PUSH    EDX
        PUSH    EAX 
        CALL    SomeProc
```

What you are doing does not do what you want:

```
        PUSH    [ESP]
```

will simply push the value (the address) on the top of the stack again, in other words, it simply duplicates the address. It does not do double indirection, i.e. it will not get the contents of the address, which is apparently what you want.